# Is it possible to create hierarchy basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

An eigenbasis is defined as basis consisting entirely of eigenvectors of a linear transformation. On the other hand a Schauder basis is also a basis except they allow for infinite sums. I could not compare both the Schauder basis and Eigenbasis clearly. Is it possible to consider eigenbasis as a sub-class of Schauder basis or these basis are ccompletely unrelated?

Answer (score 1):

An eigenbasis is a kind of basis, and a basis is a kind of Schauder basis, so, sure, an eigenbasis is a kind of Schauder basis.